# I am connecting from one service to another facing issue on conversion

Tags: java, spring

My code:

```java
final MultiValueMap<String, String> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        parts.add( "fileName", fileName );
        
        HttpHeaders xmlHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        xmlHeaders.setContentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_XML );
        
        HttpEntity<Resource> xmlEntity = new HttpEntity<Resource>( new FileSystemResource( file ), xmlHeaders );
        parts.add( "file", xmlEntity );
        
        final String url = baseurl+url;
        
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>( parts, createHttpHeadersWithToken() );
        
 String response= restTemplate.exchange( url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class );
```

Exception

Exception occured while calling post config file: {}
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class java.nio.channels.Channels$1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class java.nio.channels.Channels$1 and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap["file"]->java.util.LinkedList[0]->org.springframework.http.HttpEntity["body"]->org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource["outputStream"])

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else stumbles on this I had this same issue and resolved it by adding the produces/consumed properties to my @PostMapping in my @RestController.

Replace:

```
@PostMapping("/my/path")
```

With:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/my/path", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
```

You may change "consumes" to whatever suits your needs.